# Predictive Search - What are the responsibilities of client and the server?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I am working on a predictive search module which is a Web application. It has a UI(HTML, JS) layer and a Service layer (Java). The idea is to give user a text box wherein he can start typing and start getting the suggestions in a drop down. The user can select an item from the drop down and start typing again and now the drop down should again show suggestions. This time the suggestions are based on earlier selected suggestion.

**For Example** - 
**User Types** - What are the 
**Suggestions** - 
1) What are the paintings
2) What are the flowers
3) What are the monuments

The user selects one of the option, lets say "What are the monuments" and starts typing again. Now the suggestions should be based on monuments.

**Suggestions**
1) What are the monuments having colour
2) What are the monuments built during
3) What are the monuments built by

Lets say the user selects "What are the monuments having colour" and starts typing again.

**Now the suggestions should be**
1) What are the monuments having colour blue
2) What are the monuments having colour red
3) What are the monuments having colour white

So on and so forth.

The question is what is the responsibility of the client and the server?
1) Should the client just send the text to the Service layer and expect the suggestions as and when he types? In this case the responsibility of the server is to start parsing the text received, split into words and find out what is missing ([subject like paintings, flowers and monuments][predicate based on the subject like having colour, built during, built by] or [object based on the selected subject and predicate like blue, green and white]), and create suggestions and send them to the client. All text processing is done on the service layer.
2) Should the client while calling the service layer also send what has been already selected apart from the text itself. As in - What is the subject which is selected from the drop down, and the predicate, and the object, so on and so forth.

What should be the ideal approach?